# Getting child id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I retrieve this Id using jQuery?

```
<span data-itemkey="40e1eec6-f949-468e-8a25-ba97d0ec3fb2" class="word">
    <div class="additionalStyling green" id="2">Approval Process</div>
</span>
```

I tried this which returns `undefined`

```
 $(document).on("click", ".word", function (e) {
     var id = $(".word:first-child").attr("id");
 }
```

Comment: `.word:first-child` selects a element with the class `word`, if it is the first child of its parent.

Comment: try this $(document).on("click", ".word", function (e) {

     var id = $(this).find("div:first").attr("id");

 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
var id = $(".word:first-child").attr("id");
```

To:

```
var id = $(this).find("> div").first().attr("id");
```

Just to make sure, I am not copying the same one:

```
var id = $(this).children().first().attr('id');
```

Comment: If there is only one child `div` then no need of `first()`. Only `find()` will be enough. :)

Comment: @Sougata If that's the above case. I am just being generic. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

As there will be multiple elements with class `.word`, `$('.word')` will return a **set of elements**.

Use

```
$(this) // The element that is clicked
    .children() // Get all direct descendants
    .first() // Get first element from it
    .attr('id'); // Get the `id` attribute value
```

Answer (score 0):

[children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) accepts a selector so you can make the above shorter thus:

```
$(document).on("click", ".word", function (e) {
     var id = $(this).children(':first').attr('id');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".word", function (e) {
     var id = $(this).find('[id]').attr('id');
 });
```